# Is there a reason why the response['Items'] is returning an empty list? I'm able to print the event parameters for the test function

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

The HASH and RANGE keys for my table are 'supplier_name' and 'supplier_id', respectively. The test event is:

```
{ "supplier_name": "test","supplier_id": 123456, "key3": "value3"}
```

If I just print the event parameters, event['supplier_id'] and event['supplier_name] the return is as expected. However, for some reason the return response['Items'] is an empty list. I'm not sure if this is something to do with the sychronicity of the function call and the event or if I'm doing something completely wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

```
import boto3
from boto3.dynamodb.conditions import Key

dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
table = dynamodb.Table('MyTable')

def lambda_handler(event,context):
    
    response = table.query(
        KeyConditionExpression=Key('supplier_id').eq(event['supplier_id']) & Key('supplier_name').eq(event['supplier_name'])
        )
    return response['Items']
```

Response:

```
[]

Request ID:
"76da752a-e779-46a1-b4d3-154c4b2ca104"

Function logs:
START RequestId: 76da752a-e779-46a1-b4d3-154c4b2ca104 Version: $LATEST
END RequestId: 76da752a-e779-46a1-b4d3-154c4b2ca104
REPORT RequestId: 76da752a-e779-46a1-b4d3-154c4b2ca104  Duration: 200.42 ms Billed Duration: 300 ms Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 68 MB  Init Duration: 327.87 ms
```

Comment: Does it exist in the table?

Comment: Yes, it exists in the table. Table name is correct. I'm sure there is something obvious I'm missing.

Comment: What's the type of `supplier_id` in dynamodb? Is it stored as string?

Comment: supplier_name is a string and supplier_id is a number in both the table and the test event.

Comment: Not sure if it matters, but in my python script is able to return a csrf_token. I'd like to just get the basic function working with the test event in the aws console first though. Thanks for your help.